# What is this white stuff inside apples?

Tags: species-identification, food, mycology, health, biogeography

I live at Vancouver, BC, Canada and I often find this kind of white stuff inside the apples I buy

[image]

I used to live in Europe (Switzerland) and never saw that before. It very much look like a fungus. Is it? What species is it? What is the geographical range of this species?

When I cut my apples open, I just remove it and assume it did not lay too many mycotoxins in the rest of the apple but when I directly bite into the apple, it has happened to me to eat some of this white stuff. What are the health consequences of it?

Comment: I see it in Europe as well. I also suspect it is a fungus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it is a moldy core rot which would be caused by a fungus that infects the apple during the flowering stage. The fungi is also referred to as "apple fuzz".

---

[From SF Gate](http://www.sfgate.com/homeandgarden/goldengategardener/article/Trouble-attracting-beneficial-bugs-3653788.php)

> fungus sometimes does enter apples at the blossom end and damage the core, especially if weather is wet, a condition called "moldy core,"

---

[From PennStateExtension](http://extension.psu.edu/plants/tree-fruit/diseases/apple-diseases/moldy-core-of-apple)

> Moldy core is caused by several different fungal pathogens. Many cultivars of apples are affected, including Delicious, which is very susceptible. Moldy core may develop into dry core rot if the pathogen penetrates into the core flesh, but the fungus is generally restricted to the core or carpel region.

---

**The Disease cycle**

> The moldy core fungi colonize the flower parts as soon as the blossoms open. The fungi then enter the developing fruit through an opening in the calyx. Moldy core is primarily a problem during years with light fruit set or when dry weather in early summer is followed by heavy rains in late summer. In addition, wet weather during bloom may cause conditions favorable for the fungi to produce spores.

---

**What kind of fungi is it?**

[Mycelium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycelium)

---

**Geographical range**

The fungi is mostly found in the apple sorts “[Delicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idared)” and “[Idared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idared)”. Idared's origin is from Idaho, and delicious is originally from Iowa, USA.

---

**Is it dangerous to my health?**

Not more dangerous than usual mold would be to your health. You can find more information [here](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/molds-on-food-are-they-dangerous_/ct_index/!ut/p/a1/jZFRb8IgFIV_TR8pdHWm7q1psmg32xmziX0xKLfQpIUGcJ379UN9ctFN7hPnficXzsUVprhS7LMRzDVasfZ4r8YbsiDjaJKRvJxEz2RWfCzKlywjyfLRA-s_gCK-03_jpOQ_f37HgAczz-YCVz1zEjWq1pgKcIgpO4CxmNZac2RZDe6AarZzyEoA5xtHDZ26kineNkpg2umWW6TVWWcGkJNwQJwpAUbv7QbTnds0isMXXuHq8nkk8jUr4uVomhcxKUe_gSv5nYHbAfkERKu3p2WtU7WNE_9VAzUYMOHeeFk619ungARkGIZQaC1aCDkE5JpDauswvQBx373T79d0Spq3bpXY9AdYfoB2/#2). On some forums online I read about people consuming the white fuzz, and did mostly not complain about any problems. However, I read about one case where the fungi evoked an allergic reaction.

---

**Picture**

[image: apple mold]

---

**Further reading**

- [Principles of Forest Pathology](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9780471129523) page 558

Comment: The information from your first source is opposite to your conclusion: Dave Wilson fruit experts to whom he showed your photos agreed that the appearance of the cores is normal for Fuji apples, so the entire apple should be fine for jelly production. He said that fungus sometimes does enter apples at the blossom end and damage the core, especially if weather is wet, a condition called "moldy core," but your apples are free of fungus.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post an opposing answer, so here's a comment explaining why I disagree with your conclusion. The picture that the OP posted is very similar to normal white fuzzy tufts present in some apple cores. From PennState Extension: ["I’ve received some pictures of apples where the core has white fuzzy tufts (see pictures below). We’ve determined in the lab these “white fuzzy tufts” in the core are not fungal, but part of the apple tissue. Consequently, these apples are perfectly fine and disease-free."](http://extension.psu.edu/plants/tree-fruit/news/2017/moldy-core-of-apple)