# Could Physarum polycephalum consume regular toenail fungus?

Tags: mycology

I just watched [this video](https://youtu.be/GY_uMH8Xpy0?t=47) on [physarum polycephalum, aka the "blob"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physarum_polycephalum) and noticed how it consumes white fungus. Could it do the same maybe with human toenail fungus?

[image: blob eating white tree fungus]

Comment: I am afraid your question is expressed in non-scientific terms, and requiring one to watch an external video to understand it, is not acceptable for this list. Your question is likely to be closed for lack of clarity unless you edit it so that it becomes comprehensible in itself. “Blob” indeed!

Comment: The site shows a related question that seems to be accepted : https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/46192/what-is-this-white-stuff-inside-apples?rq=1 Your proposal sounds like a double standard :) I edited the question nevertheless.

Comment: — Unconvicted criminals do not create precedent for criminality. I know nothing about the question you refer to, and have no obligation to examine every question on this list. To accuse me of double-standards is absurd and offensive. Comments are to help people improve their questions, and I have done so in a manner that informs you of the “law”, not its transgressions. A more civil response would be to say thank you.

Comment: Thanks, of course :) The question was understandable though in layman terms, and that was the point. Science has to be inclusive and avoid scaring layman away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Toenail fungus is deep inside the toenail.**

Physarum would probably love to eat delicious toenail fungus if it could get at it.  But that fungus is down infiltrating the structure of the toenail itself, which is why topical treatments to the nail are (usually) ineffective at curing an infection with this fungus.

Toenails are durable and pretty impervious and the toenail fungus is safe down in there.  Physarum is a detrivore and I do not think has the enzymes necessary to penetrate the toenail and get to the fungus.  If it did I suspect it would be happy to eat toenail, fungus and all.  I would not want to have something like that on my toe.